# Logs not Updating in kibana automatically using filebeat

Tags: filebeat

I have installed ELK and Filebeat in two different machines(Cent OS).
My log file was there in filebeat machine.
Every time if i want to update the logs i need to run the following command "systemctl restart filebeat"
How to avoid this step? so that filebeat should able to read logfile synchronously and show it in kibana?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the `scan_frequency` option on filebeat config file.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html